# ffmpeg streaming video in Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, websocket, ffmpeg, video-streaming, raspberry-pi2

Hi im using this method http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets to stream video from my raspberry Pi cam to my pc using Websocket everything work fine but when I run ffmepg command it give me error.

Here is the full console output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f mpeg1video -b 800k -r 30 http://localhost:8082/mypassword/320/240/
ffmpeg version N-77221-g93d336f Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavcodec     57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavformat    57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 21.100 /  6. 21.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1d4b230] The device does not support the streaming I/O method.
/dev/video0: Function not implemented
```

But when I run the command from my pc using ssh to raspberry pi it work fine, any suggestion ?

Comment: Stop re-posting your questions please.

Comment: But no one give me an answer

Comment: Then be more patient. Perhaps there is no answer, perhaps those that do know it check for new questions only once in a while. Reposting it only gets you question blocked or banned.